# appending JSON array in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, ipad

So I have a JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "data": {
        "last_updated": 1342277036, 
        "stream": [
            {
                "action": {
                },
                "to": [
                ], 
                "from": [
                ],  
                "timestamp": 1342276421
            }, 
            {
                "action": {
                },
                "to": [
                ], 
                "from": [
                ],  
                "timestamp": 1342276421
            }, 
            {
                "action": {
                },
                "to": [
                ], 
                "from": [
                ],  
                "timestamp": 1342276421
            },
```

I then make another request and get the same response. I wanted to combine these two JSON, basically appending the new "stream" array that I have to the older one's. Here's what I've done so far that failed graciously:

```
NSMutableArray *streamArray = 
  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[streamDiskData valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"stream"]];
NSArray *newFeeds = [[jsonData valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"stream"];
//append the old JSON array with the new feeds stream
[streamArray insertObjects:newFeeds atIndexes:indexSet];
```

So `streamDiskData` here is the old JSON and `jsonData` is the new JSON. What am I doing wrong and how can I do this?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but if you want to make your questions as good as possible (to help us give you the best answers), there's a few things you can do: (1) the objective-c and json posted were both formatted poorly, which makes it a little harder to read, and (2) in your objc code, `indexSet` is an important variable, but you don't show us what that is.  So, that makes it harder to tell where the error is.  (3) You also didn't specify **how it failed**.  Just didn't append?  Crashed?  Didn't interleave the data at the indices? That's my best guess for why the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what your `indexSet` actually is, but try using something more like this:

```objc
NSMutableArray *streamArray = 
   [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[streamDiskData valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"stream"]];
NSArray *newFeeds = [[jsonData valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"stream"];
//append the old JSON array with the new feeds stream
[streamArray addObjectsFromArray: newFeeds];
```

`addObjectsFromArray` is what you'd use to **append** the second array.  `insertObjects:atIndexes:` is useful for inserting the `newArray` data at other locations, other than just the **end** of `streamArray`.  But, your question said **append**, so I would suggest using `addObjectsFromArray` instead.